# Google Maps API v3: Dynamically update position on polyline direction

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, react-native

Everything is running smoothly on my app. Google displays the current position and the direction polyline with start & end point.

What's missing is the famous "blue dot" that shows the current position as an overlay over the direction polyline layer as shown below:

[image]

I was thinking of setting a timer and update the "blue dot" every minute and update the position but I'm not sure if this is the correct way to implement the dynamic position.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a really good solution on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zx5xa2u/) but I don't know the author.

Instead of looping over a random array as demonstrated in the example, I actually requested the actual coordinates. My implementation is in AngularJS where I created a locationService that returns a latlng object = `{lat: <num>, lng: <num>}`

```
setInterval(function(){
  marker1.latlng = locationService.getCurrentPosition();
  marker1.draw();
}, 5000);
```

I hope that helps